# Perspective calculation in CSS3

Tags: javascript, html, css, webkit-perspective

When you use 'perspective' property in css3, in fact it gives you different element height.

```
<div style="width:200px; height:200px; -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 100%; -webkit-transform: perspective(400px) rotateX(45deg)"></div>
```

For div with height 200px,perspective 400px and rotateX 45deg, actual size will be 104px.

How can i calculate angle (45deg) for item, based on actual size (104px)?

Comment: Have a look at the [spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-transforms-1/#propdef-perspective) it should clarify how perspective works ;)

Comment: Which browser are you using and how is the height being measured? From  a quick check in Chrome, I observed `height = 200`, as expected